# How to modify the output column name from select in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am very new to Mysql sp world, so forgive me if this is a silly question

This is about variable:

I have a table something like **"_id, name"**
And I created a sp like

```
f(IN name varchar(255)
```

In sp i want to do query like :

```
select * from tb where name=@name
```

It seems you can not define a variable the same name as the field name
of a table, is it true?

At least it doesn't work for me, so i changed my sp to

```
f(IN _name varchar(255)
```

And finally I return data by

```
select _name
```

So here comes my 2ed question:
How to change column name in output from "_name" to "name"

Answer (score 0):

> It seems you can not define a variable the same name as the field name
>   of a table, is it true?

Answer: True

---

And as for your second question, you can use `as` keyword:

```
select _name as "name" ...
```

Comment: @DrewPierce you can't always modify the table: what if there are other services that use it and expect `_name` ? ;)

Comment: Thanks for your input, i will try "as" later, and alter doesn't work for me since it's not a table